# How to convert URL to a URI?

Tags: android

I am trying to cache these images using this code...

But i keep getting a syntax error here?

```
 Uri imageUri = new Uri(aURL);
```

Here is the code im using.

```
                                URL aURL = new URL(myRemoteImages[position]);



                                Uri imageUri = new Uri(aURL);
                                if (new File(new File(myContext.getCacheDir(), "thumbnails"), "" + imageUri.hashCode()).exists())
                                {
                                    String cachFile = ""+imageUri.hashCode();
                                    FileInputStream fis;

                                    try {
                                        fis = new FileInputStream(cachFile);
                                        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis); 
                                         i.setImageBitmap(bm);
                                            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                                            /* Set the Width/Height of the ImageView. */
                                            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
                                                i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(450, 300));
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(125, 125));
                                            }


                                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                                           Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remtoe Image Exception", e);





                                            /* Image should be scaled as width/height are set. */
                                            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                                            /* Set the Width/Height of the ImageView. */
                                            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
                                                i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(450, 300));

                                            return i;
                                            }
                                                i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(125, 125));
                                                return i;
                                            }
```

Comment: all URLs are URIs, but not all URIs are URLs. URIs can for example be relative paths. as long as the URL is valid (you have a java.net.URL object), you can do as niek suggested below.

Comment: Thanks Yeah i worked it out by doing imageUri = aUrl.toUri(); and walla

Comment: btw.. Could you vote my question up please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the [docs.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) You can't create an URI with an URL. Use something like

```
URI uri = new URI(aURL.toString());
```

Catching any necessary exceptions ofcourse.

Comment: URI != Uri. And that constructor does not exist.

Answer (score 9):

try this

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.net/URL/Java_URL_toURI_.htm

```
URI uri= url.toURI()
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#toURI()

See this method. It might be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromFile(java.io.File)

As far as I understand, you are trying to get the Uri of the urls you fetched from remote location. There is strong chance that the Uri wont exist on the device. Just ensure what you trying to achieve.