# Bitmap to uri conversion android?

Tags: android, uri, android-bitmap

I want to convert bitmap to URI conversion I am using google image search API from this API I got image URL from this URL I converted it to a bitmap then I want to convert from this bitmap to URI using this sample but I get a null value.

```
private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Bitmap map = null;
        for (String url : urls) {
            map = downloadImage(url);
        }
        return map;
    }

    // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        imagQest.setImageBitmap(result);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = Images.Media.insertImage(ctx.getContentResolver(),
                result, "Title", null);
        LivLog.info(this.getClass(), "bit map conversion is" + result
                + path);

    }

    // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

        try {
            stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
            // stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }
}
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: @BirajZalavadia my problem is i uploading images to amazon server using amazon api while i am using google image search api to search images from net after using this api i got one iamge url from this image url i dowload a images then i got a bitmap form this bitmap i want to convert uri for amazon iamge uploading while i coverting bitmap to uri above sample code i got null value.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you'd convert Bitmap to Uri:

```
private Uri getImageUri(Context context, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Pass Bitmap while calling this method:

```
getImageUri(this,bitmap);
```

Comment: this is deprecated and returns null now .. not working for any other solution?

Answer (score 4):

try below code:-

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
  String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
  return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

for more info see below link:-

http://colinyeoh.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/android-getting-image-uri-from-bitmap/

Comment: @Golup using above that code this line i got error fileString path = Images.Media.insertImage(ctx.getContentResolver(),    result, "Title", null); not found

Comment: @HariHaran see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864454/how-to-convert-url-to-a-uri

Comment: Isn't working on 6.0.

Also, what is the use of bytes BAOS??

Comment: did you fix it ?